# How to purge $TxF folder on NTFS drive

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, disk-space, system-restore

After I completed a restore from a checkpoint (“restore point”) in Windows 8,
5.5 GB of space disappeared from my `C:` disk.

- Before restoring, `System Volume Information\System restore` contained 5.5 GB of checkpoints; after some investigation with SpaceSniffer and OSForensics, I see folders within `C:\$extended\$TxF` now occupy 5.5 GB.
- `Chkdsk` didn't report any problems.
- I can't remove the drive because it's a Lenovo Miix 2 | 8" tablet.

Is there any way to restore this space other than formatting the partition?

Comment: Provided you have backups I would just delete the file.

Comment: If you are unable to delete the file then boot to a live environment that will allow you to delete it.

Comment: But device is table with only one USB and connect keybord, mouse and boot from usb will be tricky I think :-) Maybe best will be factory reset becouse majority of applications is metro and all user data is in cloud :-)

Comment: Have you tried Disk Cleanup, ticking the box for system files?

Answer (score 1):

From an elevated Command Prompt, run

```
fsutil behavior set DisableTxF <volume> 1
```

*`<volume>`* could be `C:`, `D:`, etc.

The command is supported by all versions of Windows that use the `$TxF` file.

Comment: I’ve made a start at improving this answer, but it needs more work. Please explain what this command does.  Is it any different in PowerShell?  For extra credit, what versions of Windows support it? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @Scott An explanation of the difference in executing a command from PowerShell vs. the Command Prompt is beyond the scope of this question.  Also, the question did not request an explanation of the purpose of the $TxF file and the ramifications of deleting it.  While I agree that explanation would be eminently useful, I did not have time to pursue such in-depth explanation.  I needed the direct command and I felt it was useful to share. I encourage someone else to post a better, more in-depth answer.

Comment: I wasn’t suggesting that you provide an explanation of the purpose of the $TxF file and the ramifications of deleting it. I was encouraging you to explain what the `fsutil behavior set DisableTxF C: 1` command *does*. While we aggressively discourage link-only answers, a link to an explanation would be better than nothing.

Comment: I don't have `DisableTxF` on Windows 7 yet it seems to access `$TxF`.